# extjs4 radioGroup setReadOnly

Tags: extjs, radio-group, readonly

Is there a way to set a radioGroup as read only. I tried disabled: true, but this creates a mask over the radioGroup which makes it practically unreadable. Any idea on how to set extjs radioGroup as readOnly please?

I'd also consider using the disabled feature if there was a way to get the masking off of the radioGroup.

UPDATE - Tried this in css using disabledCls. But it's either too dark or too white

```
.custom-disabled
{
   opacity: 0.1; // tried 0.9
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the CSS class with `disabledCls` property, if you don't like the default: try with `x-form-field`

Comment: ***disabledCls not disableCls

Comment: Thanks Wilk... I tried with the disabledCls, but I can't get the opacity to work. it's either too white or too dark ranging from 0.1 to 0.9. Is there a way to make it transparent. How would the css look like?

Comment: @EagleFox Try with: `style: 'opacity:.3'`